# Accessing variable with this returns undefined in map

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, this

I'm getting error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

when running the following:

```
function Polygon(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  this.build = function() {
    this.a.map(function(i, v) {
      console.log(this.a[v])
    });
  }
}

var square = new Polygon(300, 300);
square.build();
```

This occurs only when trying to reference the `this.a` variable within Array  functions such as `Array.prototype.map` and `reduce`. The code, however, works when storing the variable within local variable, like so:

```
function Polygon(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  this.build = function() {
    var b = this.a;
    b.map(function(i, v){
      console.log(b[v])
    });
  }
}

var square = new Polygon(300,300);
square.build();
```

My questions are:

- Why am I getting this error?
- Is there a better way to access a 'class' variable?
- Could this be a JavaScript scope bug?

Comment: I guess your map function callback arguments are not correctly matched. You are using the current value in the placeof the current index.

Comment: there is no `this.b` defined...

Comment: and `i` makes not sense because it is not the index, it is the value.

Comment: Why not just try to log `this` in both function calls, and you'll likely see that it's the global object, which has no `a` *(or `b`)* property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for `Array.prototype.map`:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to map, it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value. **Otherwise, the value undefined will be passed for use as its this value.** (Emphasis added)

This means that `this` in the `map` function is undefined, thus you're attempting to use bracket notation on `undefined`. This yields the `TypeError`, which says you're trying to access a property of `undefined`.

---

You are also incorrectly using `i`. `i` is the actual *element or item*, not the index. You can just log `i`, do not subscript `a`:

```js
function Polygon(width, height){
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  this.build = function(){
    this.a.map(function(i, v){
      console.log(i);
    }, this);
  }
}

var square = new Polygon(300, 300);
square.build();
```

This will pass the optional `thisArg` as the `Polygon`'s context and log correctly. The argument explicitly states the `this` context, allowing the access of `this.a`.

Comment: thanks ! didn't catch that ..the context of 'this' is being switched if not specified..

Comment: @KpTheConstructor `this` is being explicitly passed. The passed `this` is in the context of `Polygon`, and allows you to access `this.a`. Without passing it, you try to access `this` in `map`, which is `undefined` by default.